# Setting the variable $USERNAME has no effect

Tags: shell, zsh, environment-variables

Setting the variable USERNAME has no effect. Accessing the variable always returns the current logged in user.

```
james@localhost:~$ USERNAME=foo
james@localhost:~$ echo $USERNAME
james
```

I could not find any reference or documentation that explains this behaviour. It seems as if $USERNAME is some kind of special variable. Are there others? Where is this documented or explained?

Comment: not reproduced here. what shell are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using the *Z Shell*, at least the behavior you are describing is reproducible there:

```
zsh$ echo $USERNAME
user1
zsh$ USERNAME=test
zsh$ echo $USERNAME
user1
zsh$
```

The manpage *zshparam* gives the reason:

> **USERNAME**
>               The username corresponding to the real user ID of the shell process.  If you have sufficient privileges, you
>                 may change the username (and also the user ID and group ID) of the shell by  assigning  to  this  parameter.
>                 Also  (assuming  sufficient privileges), you may start a single command under a different username (and user
>                 ID and group ID) by `(USERNAME=username; command)'

So, with sufficient privileges, e.g. as *root* this works, but only if `user1` is a *valid* username:

```
su
zsh# echo $USERNAME
root
zsh# USERNAME=user1
zsh#  echo $USERNAME
user1
zsh# id
uid=1001(user1) gid=1000(users)   
groups=1000(users),...
```

And yes, there are other special variables, look out for the `<S>` marking in `man zshparam`, only to mention a few examples:

- `$?` exit status returned by the last command
- `$$` process ID of this shell
- `$EGID` effective  group ID of the shell process
- `$SECONDS` number  of  seconds  since  shell  invocation

Comment: This really is a zsh thing. I just recently switched to zsh and it took us quite a while to understand why our script did not run as expected anymore because the script uses a variable called USERNAME... :-|

Comment: @James: You should spend your script a `#!/bin/bash` shebang line `;)` -- except it must be _sourced_.

Comment: I'll definitively will add the shebang line!

Answer (score 0):

USER and LOGNAME are addressed in envron(7) manpage. [login(1) is the process who set these variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76354/who-sets-user-and-username-environment-variables/76356#76356).

both USER and LOGNAME variables can be modified and later access return the new value.

find nowhere the reference for USERNAME, and this variable is not set in bash4.3.
bash defines a UID readonly numerical variable. attempt to change this variable in bash fails.

[linux manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) says USER "is used by some BSD-derived
              programs" while LOGNAME "is used by some System-V derived
              programs" and [apple manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/environ.7.html) claim USER deprecated.